# Vuex, is there a cache-and-network request policy? Can I persist the store in browser for subsequent immediate visits?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, browser-cache, vuex-orm

I'm coming from years with Apollo and GraphQL.

I wanna create a small project using Vue and simple REST API.

I read about Vuex, I wanna know:

1. Is there a way to persist the store in browser so if I restart the browser window (or if I close and reopen the next day) I immediately get the data that are stale but immediate?
2. Is there a way to refetch that data from backend (using REST API calls) MEANWHILE I'm seeing the stale data? In Apollo / URQL and GraphQL world I can do this using `requestPolicy: "cache-and-network"` for each request. **Is there something similar in Vuex?**